# Add image on ffmpeg stream

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, stream, debian, sh

I'm coming to you today because I just want to add an overlay to my feed on youtube I already have all the code that plays the video but I can not add an image. Here is the code that I am currently using and I have seen on another post how to add an image but I can not add it:

```
function goto {


VBR="2000k"                                    # Bitrate de la vidéo en sortie
FPS="30"                                       # FPS de la vidéo en sortie
QUAL="fast"                                  # Preset de qualité FFMPEG
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"  # URL de base RTMP youtube

result="$(ls Video | shuf -n 1)"

SOURCE="Video/${result}"              # Source UDP (voir les annonces SAP)
KEY="ergtre498ter64t"                                     # Clé à récupérer sur l'event youtube

ffmpeg \
    -i "$SOURCE" -deinterlace -vf realtime -af arealtime \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 512k \
    -framerate 2 -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
goto
}
goto
```

And the code I found

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i image.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy \
output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg command would be

```
ffmpeg \
    -i "$SOURCE" -i "$IMAGE" -filter_complex "[0]yadif[m];[m][1]overlay=25:25,realtime" -af arealtime \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 512k \
    -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

`$IMAGE` should be set to your image file URL.

Comment: Thanks but now i cannot add:  `-deinterlace -vf realtime -af arealtime` because I mean real real time for broadcasting

Comment: You don't need to. `deinterlace` is taken over by `yadif`. `realtime` filters are still present in my command.

Comment: and how do i put the image on the whole screen?